# Looking for mobo to support pci-e x8 GPU and x8 nic

Tags: motherboard, pcie

current setup is:
**MB**: MSI H510M-A PRO
**CPU**: i5-11400
**GPU**: Gigabyte intel arc A310 Windforce (x16 physical, x8 4.0 utilized)
**M.2**: PCIe 3.0 x4

The requirement is to add 10GB-sfp+ card (currently looking into Intel X520-DA1). As I understand current, current mobo doesn't support bifurcation (or at least no such option in current BIOS firmware and no info in manual), so using riser card isn't an option seems to me (or maybe is, would be nice if there's a solution). If not - looking for a mobo replacement for the same platform (i.e. LGA1200) but to support both GPU and new NIC. NIC isn't purchased yet, so any x4 10Gb SFP NIC is also acceptable.

Comment: Welcome to Hardware Recs! I'd probably go the new motherboard route; there's lot of options though. Do you have a budget or any other feature requirements? If not, I'd probably get whatever is available in your price bracket and isn't total garbage.

Comment: Also, do you need it to be mATX, or could you go ATX? There just aren't a lot of options for mATX boards with an 8x slot.

Comment: @JMY1000 Hi, thanks for your response. It's ok for me to swap into ATX, however all I can find is something like double x16 physical but the mb manual tells it's x16/x4 which is not my case. Or maybe it is, but then I need something like PCIe-3.0 x4 nic, but the options I found are like at least 5 times costlier than X520. There's no other special requirements, I just want to add 10gig while not opting out of GPU and all other components (i.e. lga1200 cpu and ddr4). The system is build for surveillance client.

Comment: That single x16 slot is supposed to be wired to the CPU and therefore the CPU's PCIe controller is the one that needs to support bifurcation. If there was no setting in the BIOS that might only mean the southbridge lanes don't support bifurcation. If somebody knows about this please share info on CPUs supporting bifurcation on their own lanes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Buy a used Q570/Z590 board

Q470, Z490, W480, Q570, Z590, and W580 [all support a a 2x8 configuration for CPU PCI-e lanes.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1200) However, I believe only Q570, Z590, and W580 are *guaranteed* to support a 2x8 CPU + 1x4 chipset configuration for PCI-e lanes, though some Z490 boards such as the Maximus XII Hero do support it. These boards should support your current hardware without the need for bifurcation.

I believe any board on [this list](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/motherboard/#xcx=0&s=39&h=2,8&sort=price&c=157,148&E=1,7) should work for you; currently, the cheapest board available new is the MSI MAG Z590 TORPEDO at $238.98. That's pretty pricy for an older board; given that this generation hasn't been current for a little while, I think you'll be better off with a used board.

Aside: If you're having trouble finding a used board, I can help point you to some specific listings.